# Access Ingress logs

Tags: ingress

Is there a way to get access to the logs for the last few weeks, with all actions in a given map area/everything? Is there an API?

I'd like to create some art projects on Ingress about fields, time-lapse and so on.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there's no public API for Ingress. It's been talked about for years, and the developers are not against the idea, but there are no recent news about a development.

There is anyway a source where you can get some data that may be useful for your projects, [Ingress Intel](https://www.ingress.com/intel): this is the official intel map of the game, with logs and map positions. At high zoom levels (i.e. when showing the whole world) it can be painfully slow, since it tries to load every L8 portal on the planet. Focusing on narrower zones though you can see links and fields, and get some informations about single portals. Refreshing the map you can update the informations and let you take time-lapse screenshots of a specific region.

Be careful with the map: if you're planning to use automated tools to retrieve informations, your account may be banned, since the ToS specifically prevents you to access the data with automated tools, bots et al. You may anyway create a throwaway account just for this task, since every information on the map is accessible at any Agent level.

Comment: Technically, creating a throwaway account is also against ToS. I am giving you +1 for your answer anyway.

Answer (score -1):

There is no API to retrieve logs.

Extracting data automatically is against Term of Service. 
However, many players uses IITC, that is tolerated because standard Intel doesn't works very well. Don't expect to get weeks of data from logs anyway.

Comment: Be wary: tolerated doesn't mean it's safe to use. Being a plugin for the Intel map it falls in the "automated tools" that are specifically prohibited by the ToS. You may use it safely for months then have Niantic change the way the Intel works and be banned (it happened to some with an older version of IITC). I've used IITC myself and yes, it's easier to use than the standard map, and you can retrieve more informations through it, but you have to consider if it's worth it.

Comment: IITC is not tolerated, especially some of the settings and plug-ins may get you banned instantly. However, IITC can run in a noninvasive mode where it behaves just like normal intel, which is undetectable and may create impression that it is tolerated.

Comment: Most players consider using IITC acceptable behavior. Especially players involved in large teams operations. Sitreps claims using IITC, without anyone in Niantic objecting.